# HostListner making page scroll unresponsive

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

Angular version : 6.0.0

Cli : 6.0.0

I have used following HostListener to show the scroll to top button if page is scrolled 500px or more, and vice-versa.

```
isSectionFixed : boolean = false;
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event.target'])
onWindowScroll(event) {
    let number = window.pageYOffset ||  0;
    if (number > 500) {
        this.isSectionFixed = true;
    } else if (this.isSectionFixed && number < 500) {
        this.isSectionFixed = false;
    }
}
```

It works well but page becomes unresposive.

This code is used in `app.component.ts`

Only few pages gets unresponsive like amazon like product search page but with infinite scroll.

I have also tried with `Observable`

```
eventSubscription = Observable.fromEvent(window, "scroll").subscribe(e => {
    this.scrollY = window.scrollY;
});
```

It works well until I add some code inside the `onWindowScroll` function or in 2nd case in the `subscribe callback`.

Same solution works well in a Server side redered angular app.

Any help would be appreciated, I can't share the link to app it's private right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the operators [throttletime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime) and [distinctUntilChanged](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) on your scroll Observable, so that scroll events aren't mapped to a value as often and you only emit a new boolean value if it actually changed.

```ts
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, takeUntil, throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

const scrolledDown$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
  throttleTime(10), // only emit scroll events every 10 ms, set this to your needs
  map(() => window.pageYOffset > 500), // map to a boolean value  
  distinctUntilChanged(), // only emit if the value has changed
  takeUntil(this.destroy$) // unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed
);

private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

`scrolledDown$` will emit a boolean value indicating whether the user scrolled below a certain point (whether `window.pageYOffset` is larger than 500). This is essentially your `isSectionFixed` value as an Observable.

Either subscribe to `scrolledDown$` with the `asnyc` pipe in your template or manually in your code if you have to. If you subscribe manually don't forget to unsubscribe when the component gets destroyed (that's what `destroy$` is for in my code).

**Edit**

You could also try to improve scoll performance by making your event listeners [passive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners). You can achieve this easily with [default-passive-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/default-passive-events).

Comment: it still slows down the page even if i put 5 sec of time, if I remove all these things it works well

Comment: @Rakeschand strange. So a simple `console.log()` in the `subscribe` makes the scrolling laggy for you? Have you tried different browsers and devices?